# Alternatives to ID Selector?

Tags: openid

Anybody knows a good alternative to ID Selector since it's now RPX and at least for me, won't be good?

thanks

Comment: Just curious: Why won't RPX work for you?

Comment: For the same reasons described here http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/01/why-using-rpxnow-is-bad-idea.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Open-selector](http://open-selector.com/). It was created as an alternative to ID Selector.

From the documentation:

> Open-selector is a piece of Javascript
>   code that will take your existing
>   OpenID login textbox and change it
>   into a Provider selection list, that
>   the user can complement with their
>   username to build their OpenID URL.

You have total control over Open-selector, including the ability to add your own providers to the list.

Comment: I haven't tried installing it myself, but the demo at http://open-selector.com/ works fine in Firefox and Safari. Can you describe the problem you're experiencing? Alternatively, you can file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/open-selector/issues/list and request help from the author.

Comment: I just tested with rev12(the current version on the official page) and it seems to work with IE7 and 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of Open-selector :)

When I first made it, it did not work on any IE (thus the google code issue), I just tested on IE6 and 7 and it seems to work ok! (current checkout). Although I'm looking for other people to confirm this.

The styles on the open-selector.com site may look clumsy, but that's just my clumsy CSS, Open-selector does not provide styling, so you can alter the alignment and position with CSS if needeed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GIGYA as an alternative of RPX. here is link : http://www.gigya.com

Comment: Have you tried this? Let me know by a reply if more help needed.